# Php, Regex preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I am using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), Here is what i am trying to do:

```
$result = '[code]some code here[/code]';

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/is', function($matches){
      return '<div>'.trim($matches[1]).'</div>';
}, $result);
```

The idea is to replace every match of **[code] with `<div>`** and **[/code] with `</div>`**, And trim the code between them.

The problem is with this string for example:

```
$result = '[code]some code[/code]some text[code]some code[/code]';
```

What i want the result to have **2 separated** div's:

```
$result = '<div>some code</div>some text<div>some code</div>';
```

**The result i get is:**

```
$result = '<div>some code[code]some text[/code]some code</div>';
```

Now i know the reason, And i understand the regex but i couldn't come up with solution, If anyone know how to make it work i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Try a non-greedy regex: `/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is greedy matchiing:

```
/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/is
```

Should behave as you want it to.

Regex Repetition is *greedy*, which means it captures as many matching items as it can, then gives up one match at a time if it finds that it can't match what's left after the repetition.  By using a question mark, you indicate that you want to match non-greedily, or *lazily*, meaning that the engine will try to match the rest of the regular expression FIRST, then grow the size of the repetition after.

Comment: I'm glad, make sure you hit "accept" so others know at first glance what worked for you.

Comment: In about 6min, Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `preg_replace_callback()` since you can extract the "trimed" content:

```
$pattern = '~\[code]\s*+((?>[^[\s]++|\s*+(?!\[/code])\[?+)*+)\s*+\[/code]~i';
$replacement = '<div>$1</div>';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $result);
```